# Property about $a+b=0$

Tags: metric-spaces, arithmetic

We know well that $$ab=0\iff a=0 \vee b=0.$$
Is there any property that says about $a+b=0$? What about
$$a+b=0 \stackrel{?}\iff a=0\wedge b=0.$$
Note that I do not deny that there are many solutions of it. I was studying about the metric for fun and the proof of 1) condition on [taxicab metric is a metric](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081002151759AAUZGTU) made me think about this property.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not deny that there are many solutions of it?"

Comment: @MiloBrandt I mean that there can be many solutions. For example (a,b) = (-4,4), so a + b = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know $a,b\ge 0$, it is true. For instance
$$a^2+b^2=0\implies a^2=b^2=0\iff a=b=0,$$
$$\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b \rvert=0\implies \lvert a\rvert=\lvert b \rvert=0\iff a=b=0.$$

Comment: The former is only true when $a$ and $b$ are real, of course.

Comment: I wrote $a, b\ge 0$…

Comment: I was referring to the $a^2+b^2=0$ one. We only have $a^2,b^2\ge0$ when $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, but this was implicit.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
a=0 \land b=0 \Rightarrow a+b=0
$$
is true, but
$$
a+b=0 \Rightarrow a=0 \land b=0
$$
is false  (in a ring).